# Не работает ограничение на тип вводимых данных JS

Tags: javascript

Не понимаю, почему любое вводимое значение в поле в консоли отображается как строка (будь то символ или число).
В чем некорректность кода?

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
  let a = prompt("Какой тип товаров будем продавать?", '');
  if ( typeof(a) === 'string' && a !== null && a !== '' ) {
    console.log("Все верно!");
    mainList.shopGoods[i] = a;
    console.log(typeof(a));
  } else {
      console.log("incorrect data type");
  }
}
```

заранее спасибо.

Comment: Потому что функция `prompt` возвращает строку или `null`.

Comment: _Return value: A string containing the text entered by the user, or null_ - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Comment: Если вы хотите убедиться, что ввели именно строку (без чисел или символов), то это можно сделать с помощью регулярок